# how to select object in weight paint mode 4.0?

Tags: weight-painting

[image]
When I turn on Weight Paint mode and activate Pose mode, I can't select objects. I've also unlocked the object mode. I've checked the keymaps and tried everything, but nothing seems to work. What should I do?
The image shows a control bone, but it doesn't indicate any pink-colored connections.
It is a blender 4.0.

Comment: try updating to blender 4.0.1. They fixed a few bugs since then.

Comment: I update blender but It still continue.. but other file is well, specific file is bug. thank you

Comment: if the file is somehow bugged, try to copy your model and armature with ctrl+C, and paste it in a new clean file with ctrl+V

Comment: wow. thank you sir. it is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the pose mode x-ray mode is disabled. It's a really not so obvious mode that locks you into Pose Mode and that can be easily enabled by mistake.
[image]

If this doesn't work, you can just use go to weight paint mode and use the shortcut for "weight paint sample group" which allows you to select a vertex group of your mesh which is under your mouse cursor. Might be less hurdle if you know your bones names well.